# Check if axes GUI is empty or not in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

How to check if axes are entered empty or not?

This is my simple program screen:

[image: program screen]

Comment: try with: `isEmpytAxes = isempty(get(AxesHandle, 'Children'))`

Comment: Please define "empty".